# Pronoun missing?

Tags: ellipsis, clauses, free-relative-clauses

A line in the movie *Stargate* goes

> It's got writing unlike we've ever found before.

It seems to me this sentence is missing a pronoun *what/anything*. Is this a case of ellipsis? Is it grammatical as it stands? Is the second half of the sentence still a noun clause/free relative clause?

Shouldn't the sentence be

> It's got writing unlike **what/anything** we've ever found before.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a word is missing. Rather than adding "anything," the writer could add "any" (which would be understood to mean "any writing," without having to use the word "writing" twice in the sentence.